# Making my Linux (Ubuntu) to ask me what is the SQL password so I won't store it in the .sh file?

Tags: mysql-connection

I have a a script file which makes an immediate backup of my server's document root and of my databases and copy it to my terminal system, from which I SSH tunneled to my server environment:

```
(
cd /var/www/html
zip -r ./html.zip ./
mysqldump -u USER -p PASSWORD --all-databases > ./db.sql
zip backup.zip html.zip db.sql
scp backup.zip /home/user/backups
rm ./html.zip ./db.sql ./backup.zip
)
```

### My problem:

Where it is PASSWORD, I need to manually type my password. This is something I want to avoid because I internalized this password into my mind and also use it frequently, and don't want to type it inside the script.

### My ideal:

I would rather prefer to be promped for my password each time I do the following command (or something of that sort):

```
mysqldump -u USER --all-databases > ./db.sql
```

### My question:

Is having such a prompt possible via Linux itself or via some existed utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From mysqldump manpage:

```
 o   --password[=password], -p[password]

           The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the
           --password or -p option on the command line, mysqldump prompts for one.

           Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. You can use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line.
```

Just omit the password value in `-p` flag and mysqldump will prompt for password.